# supplied resource is not a valid SSH2 SFTP resource

Tags: php, libssh2

```
<?php
$ssh = ssh2_connect('domain.tld');
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'username', 'password');

$start = microtime(true);
$sftp = fopen('ssh2.sftp://'.$ssh.'/home/username/1mb', 'w');

fwrite($sftp, str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024));
$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "took $elapsed seconds";
```

That code snippet gives me a

> PHP Warning: fopen(): supplied resource is not a valid SSH2 SFTP resource in ...

error. Why?

```
$sftp = fopen('ssh2.sftp://username:password@domain.tld:22/home/user/1mb', 'w');
```

That one works just fine but it wouldn't work if you were doing public key authentication, for example.

Comment: http://php.net/ssh2_sftp <- you must use the correct function to create `$ssh`.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Want to make that an answer instead of a comment so I can mark that as the answer? :)

Comment: Worked for me. Not sure why this was closed.

Answer (score 4):

As hakre mentioned in comment you should use

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect('domain.tld');
$resSftp= ssh2_sftp($ssh);
$sftp = fopen('ssh2.sftp://'.$resSftp.'/home/username/1mb', 'w');
```